# ActionLink with glyphicon-home

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

i try to set a glyphicon-home with ActionLink in my navbar . Actually i have found a similar case but it work with href.
this is my code

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Index", "manage")
                   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                Start</li>

                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Kontakt", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
```

thanks

Comment: You cannot - the `ActionLink()` method does not include an overload that allows that. You need to manually generate your `<a>` tag (but you can use `Url.Action()` to generate the `href` attribute)

Answer (score 1):

How I do,

```
<li>
  <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Manage")">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> //You can add text here too
  </a>
</li>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Manage", new {@class = "glyphicon glyphicon-home})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Start","Index", "Manage", new {@class = "glyphicon glyphicon-home"})
```